# SharePoint Validation: If Empty or Null

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column-formula, column-validation

I need help with a validation formula in a SharePoint Text column where:

- column can be empty ( the default state when list is opened)
- column can be null (the state after a value is deleted)
- must be all numbers
- must be 8 digits long

My unsuccessful try:

```
=OR(ISBLANK(FCN]),(FCN]=""),""),AND(LEN([FCN])=8,ISNUMBER([FCN]+0)))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this formula:

```
=OR(ISBLANK([FCN]),[FCN]="",AND(ISNUMBER([FCN]),LEN([FCN])=8))
```

**OR**:

```
=OR(ISBLANK([FCN]),[FCN]="",AND(ISNUMBER([FCN]+0),LEN([FCN])=8))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14))

Comment: Ganesh! #2 did the trick.  Thank you very much for all your steady help!
Cheers-